# Cannot convert value of type 'MockURLSession' to expected argument type 'MockURLSession?' error

Tags: ios, swift, mocking, xctest, urlsession

I have a function I'm trying to unit test by injecting a mockURLSession as a parameter:

```
internal func getConnection(urlRequest: Request, mockUrlSession: MockURLSession?) {

    if mockUrlSession == nil {
        let dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest)
         dataTask.resume()
    } else {

        let dataTask = mockUrlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

but when I try to unit test it I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'MockURLSession' to expected argument
>   type 'MockURLSession?'

this is the unit test:

```
 func test_urlSession404(){
        let mockResponse = HTTPURLResponse(url: (self.urlRequest?.url!)!, statusCode: 404, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: nil)!
        var mockSession = MockURLSession(mockResponse: mockResponse)
        sut?.getConnection(urlRequest: self.urlRequest!, mockUrlSession: mockSession)//error here
    }
```

even if I don't make the MockURLSession parameter optional the error still appears minus the ? at the end of MockURLSession. I'm pretty confused because they are of same type, why can't it convert, is there a way to make it so the mockURLSession can be injected?

Comment: Is it possible that you have defined `MockURLSession` twice in separate modules?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I think that may have been it.